# Create a Custom Symfony2 Form Field Type & Embed Collection For It

Tags: javascript, php, forms, symfony

I am trying to create a many to many form field modification using the following cookbook entry:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms

The idea is simple that I have the entities VendorKind, Vendor & Event. So in the event creation form, I want a field to show the values of VendorKind in a select field and based on the input, it will show the vendors values in a multi-select field.

Now since there isn't only one kind of vendor in an event (VendorKind). I want to create a custom Symfony2 form field that shall consider the select and the corresponding multi-select field as one. Which I can then use as a collection and add as many as I want using prototype.

Please let me know if this is possible using custom field type?

Comment: some code would be great...